# Find if request is trying to access a protected page in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony3.x

I'm trying to create an EventListener in Symfony that listens for the master request and if the request is trying to access a route behind a firewall to set a flag in the session. E.g. if the request is to a firewalled /admin then the EventListener should create a flag in 
 the session. The only way I can think of is to inject the user and the AccessDecisionManager and to check if the user has access to the page when the role is set to IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY and to check if the user is fully authenticated. Something similar to:

```
if (!$uthorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') && is  $authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        // the user can't access the resources when ANONYMOUS
       // this must be a secured resource
    }
```

Is there more elegant way to achieve this? There must be a method that I'm missing that simply tells you that the request is trying or has accessed a protected page. Probably listening for for some firewall events is also an option?

Answer (score 0):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Look at the access controls section. You can basically specify the routes that need to be authenticated based on a certain role. Then for all of those routes, you can just set the flag without having to do this check, since by default it won't let in an unauthorized user

Comment: Yes, I have thought about this, but I was wondering if there is another way as I don't want to pollute all controllers with some logic(the task is really irrelevant and It will not be justifiable). Thus I'm looking for a solution on a global level. Probably listening to events fired by the security component? Something that tells me "ok, I've just rendered a secured page behind a Firewall"

Comment: You write your own authenticator, use acl to make sure that pages that match a wild card will use your own authenticator, and put the shared code in there, so you only do it once

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_password_authenticator.html